# Calculating constant

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, initial-value-problems

I am solving an initial value problem :
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y(-2t+\frac1{t})$$
After integrating I am stuck on:
$$\log( y) = -t^2+\log( t) + c$$
The given initial condition is $y(0)=1$. 
Here the value of $t = 0$ and $\log(t)$ is undefined. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution satisfying that initial condition.  Note that the differential equation itself is undefined at $t=0$.  It turns out that all solutions have $y(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$.

BTW, you made a small error in the integration.  The right side should have been $-t^2 + \log(t) + c$.  But that doesn't affect the conclusion.

Comment: So I should just say that this equation is not defined at t = 0, right?

Comment: @PARTHOZA: Assuming you wrote the equation and initial conditions down properly, then yes, you would say "there is no solution satisfying this initial condition"

Comment: Yes. The equation is correct. There are actually 2 conditions in this problem. 1) dy/dt = y(-2t+1/t) when t not equal to zero and 2) dy/dt = 1 when t=0. The initial condition is y(0)=1

Answer (score 0):

First, you made a mistake, Integration yields
$$
\ln y = -t^2+\ln t +c
$$
and exponentiating yields
$$
y = e^c t e^{-t^2}
$$
and now you can apply the initial condition to see that you always get $1 = y(0) = 0$, and hence there is no solution corresponding to that initial condition.

Comment: This does not fix his problem. The condition $y(0) = 1$ is still incompatible with your solution.

Comment: This still wouldn't work.

Comment: @PARTHOZA fixed